# Working datetime between php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm just want to check if my way is correct or not. I want to calculate the remaining time for an event.

There are 3 component for it.

- The start datetime (in mysql datetime), which is retrieved from mysql.
- The duration (minutes in integer), which is also retrieved from mysql.
- The current datetime, which is retrieved from php function now().

To count:

- The remaining time (in time hh:mm:ss), which is from formula `(start + duration) - now`

My propose code is:

```
$row = data->fetch_assoc();
$start = $row["start_time"]; // e.g: "2015-06-19 09:37:16"
$duration = $row["duration"]; // e.g: 60 (minutes)
$now = time(); // e.g: 1434648994
$start_dt = strtotime ($start);

$remaining = ($start_dt + $duration * 60) - $now;

echo "Remaining time: ".$remaining. " seconds."
```

Is this correct?

Comment: does `$remaining` give you the correct amount of seconds?

Comment: See https://eval.in/383950

Comment: @Castis It wasn't. But then after some more exploration, I then realized that I haven't set the default time zone. After I set the default time zone, it returns correct result. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the code. It gives me some more insight about what can be done in php datetime, and I'm considering using your code variation. Thanks!

Comment: Mind that the php time and mysql time may not even be configured in the same timezone. Ideally you want to make sure all those values are set by the same system. Also careful with any daytime savings issues.

Comment: Yeah. I was surprised that I have problems with timezone settings, as these both are still in my local machine. The mysql returns correct time, but the php returns time 5 hours later than the mysql version. Is mysql automatically retrieve timezone settings from OS settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your code now calculates time until the end of the event.

And if `$start_dt` is lower then `$now` you get negative value.

Comment: Yeah, but it wasn't. There are an unexplainable 18000 seconds difference in the result. But then after some exploration, I realized I haven't set the timezone yet. After I set the timezone, it returns correct result to the end of event. Thanks.